# Geocoding Address name from Database using leaflet esri plugin

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding, esri

I am trying to build a map app that use address name in data base and display marker in leaflet map. I had come across leaflet esri plugin but not sure how to use the code. Could anyone please teach me how to extract result(longitude and latitude) from the geocoding function and draw a marker? Thanks!

Geocode function:

```
L.esri.Geocoding.geocode(<Object> options)
```

Results:

```
{results: [
    {
      latlng: L.LatLng,
      text: 'Formatted Address',
      score: 100, // certainty ranking of the match
      properties: {
        // additional info like specific address components (Country Code etc.)
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/geocode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using ES6:

```
import L from "leaflet";
// import library as ELG
import * as ELG from "esri-leaflet-geocoder";

// here is an example address in the US - use the one from your DB
const address = "380 New York St, Redlands, California, 92373";

// call geocode method of the library, no need to call L.esri.Geocoding.geocode() as in vanilla js
ELG.geocode()
  // pass the address
  .text(address)
  .run((err, results, response) => {
    console.log(results.results[0].latlng);
    // retrieve latitude, longitude from related response
    const { lat, lng } = results.results[0].latlng;
    // build a marker using the retrieved address
    L.marker([lat, lng])
      .addTo(mymap)
      .bindPopup(address)
      .openPopup();
});
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/58q9r588p)

Comment: Thanks kboul, but what is the geocode method? isn't it L.esri.Geocoding.geocode()?

Comment: The geocode method intializes a new geocoding task similar to `L.esri.Geocoding.geocode(<Object> options)` but in the ES6 way. When you importing a file using `import` you create a [namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults) and then you can access all the available methods as you would do it using vanilla js. 
Check also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239392/how-do-you-add-external-javascript-libraries-using-es6-style-imports) regarding on how to add external libraries using ES6 import.

Comment: @NigelNg Please accept the answer if it helped you so other users can reach your question if they have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, novice in stack overflow here.

Comment: Hello, i have a question about add many pop up to my map, i use to try a for(let i = 0; <response.lenght; i++) and do const { lat, lng } = results.results[i].latlng; 
But it's only take the first address i have and not the other on. @kboul have you already try do load many address ? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Please ask this question in a separate thread